# Twitter Bootstrap, not bootstrapping

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to use twitter bootstrap on my project. BTW, I'm also using SpringMVC My problem is that bootstrap is not bootstrapping. Anyway here are some screenshots:

**When running the app**

[image]

My project structure:

**NOTE:I'M NOT USING MAVEN, JUST PLAIN OLD DYNAMIC WEB PROJECT**

[image]

Part2 :[image]

[And the source code to my index.jsp](http://pastebin.com/NwHKw39Q)

if you want any more part of the code you can ask me. Thanks.

**update:** tried viewing the page source via firefox it seems that there's something wrong on these lines `<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-united.css" rel="stylesheet" />` and `<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js">` when clicking them they lead me to the apache 404 error page. though I can't figure out how to fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources in `/WEB-INF` are not publicly accessible. The `/WEB-INF` folder is intented for configuration files, template files, tag files, MVC views, etc. Files which should never be individually accessible by the enduser/attacker.

Move the `/assets` folder one level up.

Answer (score -2):

on this part..

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-united.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

try changing it to..

```
<link href="webcontent/web-inf/assets/css/bootstrap-united.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="webcontent/web-inf/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

or if can provide the base_url code

Comment: Tried it. Still not bootstrapping.